# Как адаптировать кнопки для версии на мобильном?

Tags: html, css

Нужно сделать так что бы они были в два ряда на мобильном а не в один.

```css
.social_as {
 
  padding:0;
  
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;

}

.social_as ul {
  position:relative;
  display: flex;
 
  
  flex-wrap: wrap;

  
  margin:110px;
  padding:0;
  justify-content: space-around;
}


}


.social_as ul li {
  list-style:none;
  margin: 25px 25px;
}

ul li a .fa {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #262626;
  line-height:80px;
  transition: .5s;
  padding-right: 14px;
}

ul li a span {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  position:absolute;
  top: 30px;
  color: #262626;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  transition: .5s;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display:absolute;
  display:block;
  width:210px;
  height:80px;
  background: #fff;
  text-align:left;
  padding-left: 20px;
  transform: rotate(-30deg) skew(25deg) translate(0,0);
  transition:.5s;
  box-shadow: -20px 20px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
ul li a:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top:10px;
  left:-20px;
  height:100%;
  width:20px;
  background: #b1b1b1;
  transform: .5s;
  transform: rotate(0deg) skewY(-45deg);
}
ul li a:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom:-20px;
  left:-10px;
  height:20px;
  width:100%;
  background: #b1b1b1;
  transform: .5s;
  transform: rotate(0deg) skewX(-45deg);
}

ul li a:hover {
  transform: rotate(-30deg) skew(25deg) translate(20px,-15px);
  box-shadow: -50px 50px 50px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

ul li:hover .fa {
  color:#fff;
}

ul li:hover span {
  color:#fff;
}

ul li:hover:nth-child(1) a{
  background: #3b5998;
}
ul li:hover:nth-child(1) a:before{
  background: #365492;
}
ul li:hover:nth-child(1) a:after{
  background: #4a69ad;
}

ul li:hover:nth-child(2) a{
  background: #e4405f;
}
ul li:hover:nth-child(2) a:before{
  background: #d81c3f;
}
ul li:hover:nth-child(2) a:after{
  background: #e46880;
}

ul li:hover:nth-child(3) a{
  background: #dd4b39;
}
ul li:hover:nth-child(3) a:before{
  background: #b33a2b;
}
ul li:hover:nth-child(3) a:after{
  background: #e66a5a;
}

ul li:hover:nth-child(4) a{
  background:#00aced;
}
ul li:hover:nth-child(4) a:before{
  background: #097aa5;
}
ul li:hover:nth-child(4) a:after{
  background: #53b9e0;
}
```

```html
<div id="social_as" class="social_as">
       
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="https://t.me/Studiolash_ru">
      <i class="fa fa-telegram" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <span>Telegram</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="https://instagram.com/studiolash.ru?igshid=YmMyMTA2M2Y=">
      <i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <span>Instagram</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCZhfzmiQ2VlMdm2rbXd2HNA">
      <i class="fa fa-youtube" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <span>YouTube</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="https://vk.com/studiolashru">
      <i class="fa fa-vk" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <span> VK</span>
    </a>
  </li>
```

Comment: "ul li a" уменьшайте ширину пока не встанут в два ряда

Comment: нет это совсем не то

Comment: По вопросу то, а по вашему что не понятно

Comment: уменьшается ширина кнопки. а мне нужно что бы в мобильной версии сайта  кнопки были в две колонки

Comment: А как они поместятся в две колонки, если места не хватает для двух колонок при такой ширине кнопки? Или кнопка должна вертикальной стать и текст идти сверху вниз?

Comment: да менял я ширину. толку ноль. мне надо их адаптировать в мобильную версию

Comment: мужик выставь им какие нужно параметры через @media